# append() adding content inconsistently

Tags: jquery

I have the below HTML code:

```html
<table id="tutorial" width="600" border="1">
<tr>
    <td data-value="a">a</td>
    <td>apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td data-value="b">b</td>
    <td>ball</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td data-value="c">c</td>
    <td>cat</td>
</tr>
```

and the below JavaScript:

```
$('#tutorial').find('tr').each (function(t) {
  $(this).append('<td>',$('td', this).data('value'),'</td>')
});
```

jQuery adds the data-value after adding the first and the last parameter. So it is like this: `<td></td>a`. The required behavior is `<td>a</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).append('<td>' + $('td', this).data('value') + '</td>')`

(basically just change the commas to pluses)

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/bunare/1/edit)

Comment: The short and sweet answer

Answer (score 2):

You want to append the value to your new `td`, but your `append` will add each item as a child of the `tr` you're calling it on.

It's as though you said:

```
$(this).append('<td>');                       // creates a new, complete TD
$(this).append($('td', this).data('value'));  // stick some text after the TD
$(this).append('</td>');                      // nothing to close, discarded
```

You want this:

```
$('<td>').                            // create a TD
  text($('td', this).data('value')).  // set its text content
  appendTo(this);                     // append to the row
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you need to write the jQuery to get the desired effect:

```
$('#tutorial').find('tr').each (function() {
    $(this).append( $('<td/>',{text:$('td',this).data('value')}) )
});
```